# check if update statement has been executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

`mysqli_affected_rows` is a strange behavior. It won't return 1 if `fname` is updated, probably caused by 2 times of `mysqli_query`. I can get 1 if another field is updated.

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE persons SET fname='$fname' WHERE id='$id'");
mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET knife='$knife', other='$other' WHERE person_id='$id'");

if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) > 1){
        echo json_encode(array(
        'id' => (int)$id,
        'fname' => $fname,
        'tools' => array(
            'knife' => $knife,
            'other' => $other
        )
    ));
}
```

So how to return updated row in my situation now?

Comment: You have to call it for each individual query, it doesn't add them all up for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your correct in your assumption that as the second query has been run, this will give a different result, so the best thing to do is restructure your code slightly to...

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE persons SET fname='$fname' WHERE id='$id'");

if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) >= 1){
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET knife='$knife', other='$other' WHERE person_id='$id'");
    echo json_encode(array(
        'id' => (int)$id,
        'fname' => $fname,
        'tools' => array(
            'knife' => $knife,
            'other' => $other
        )
    ));
}
```

(Just updated it to say `>=1` as this would - I assume be OK if just 1 row was updated)

Although I would also recommend looking into prepared statements and binding the values rather than directly putting values into SQL statements.

You should also check at each point if your query execution has failed... Something like

```
if ( !mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET knife='$knife', other='$other' WHERE person_id='$id'"))  {
   die ( "Error-".mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Or if you can update anything or nothing, then...

```
mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE persons SET fname='$fname' WHERE id='$id'");
$rowsUpdated = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);

mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE tools SET knife='$knife', other='$other' WHERE person_id='$id'");
$rowsUpdated += mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);
if ($rowsUpdated >= 1){
    echo json_encode(array(
        'id' => (int)$id,
        'fname' => $fname,
        'tools' => array(
            'knife' => $knife,
            'other' => $other
        )
    ));
}
```

Which just adds up the totals rows updated across both SQL statements.

Comment: hmm this is not working too, user not necessary have to update name, they can update ONLY tools

Comment: I've added a new version which keeps count of rows from each update.

Comment: this make sense, but is it that tedious ? I found php suck.

Comment: if the query success user should see reflected version also, not sure I want to go with this updated row approach.